# local database sql query in a loop

Tags: javascript, database, html, external, local

I created a html5  local database and I would like loop on a query and use external variables in the query callback.

The exemple below is not what I want to do but it explain my problem :

**code:**

```
db.transaction(function (tx)
{
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
   {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT title FROM podcast WHERE given_id = ' + i, undefined, function (tx, result)
      {
        console.log(result.rows.item(0).title);
        console.log(i);
      });
   }
});
```

**log:**

```
episode1
4
episode2
4
episode3
4
```

the result is perfect but I can't use "i" inside the callback, the value is always the value at the end of the loop.
How can I use external var in the callback ?
Thank

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT title,given_id FROM podcast WHERE given_id = ' + i, undefined, function (tx, result) {
         console.log(result.rows.item(0).title);
         console.log(result.rows.item(0).given_id);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank but in fact it is for the exemple, I need an external var with nothing related to the database

Comment: What is your external variable? If it's just the loop counter 'i', you can just pull out "console.log(i);" from the callback..

Comment: I have an array and i'll push in the array the different query results